# Larvel Query Builder group By with pluck

Tags: php, laravel, group-by, query-builder, pluck

| id | agent_id | currency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A0001 | IDR |
| 2 | A0002 | MYR |
| 3 | A0001 | THB |

Example currently has a dataset as above. Is there a way using only 1 query builder to get the outcome like below?

```
Output：

[
        "agent_id" => "A0001",
        "currency" => [
            "IDR",
            "THB",
    ],
],
[
        "agent_id" => "A0002"
        "currency" => ["MYR"]
]
```

Basically like trying to pluck the currency under same agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this problem

```
   $output = $output
    ->get()
    ->groupby('agent_id')
    ->map(function($rows){
      return [
        "agent_id" => $rows[0]['agent_id'],
        "currency" => $rows->pluck('currency'),
      ];
   });
```